# Why is the data sent using socket.io invisible to the user?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, google-chrome-devtools

I have always been convinced that the Google Chrome developer tools keep track of all the data sent by the website.

Then I found out about `Node.JS` and its plugin `Socket.IO`. In the demo on the socket.io website, you are able to send messages in a chat. When someone types something in the chat it is displayed in an instance on your screen.

[image: Chat]

It doesn't seem logical that the packets sent between the server and the client are invisible to the user. Why is Google Chrome not showing these packets in the network tab in the developer tools while these chat events are using internet connections?

Comment: At first time you need reload the page with Network tool opened, filter the websocket connections. In the websocket instance you need click and check the frame tab.. In this tab there are all information passed by websocket.

Answer (score 1):

It should show you some requests.

[image]

Try reloading the page with the network panel opened.